# Use same boost:thread variable to create multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

In the following example(not all the code included just the necessary portions):

```
class A
{
public:
void FlushToDisk(char* pData, unsigned int uiSize)
{
    char* pTmp = new char[uiSize];
    memcpy(pTmp, pData, uiSize);
    m_Thread = boost::thread(&CSimSwcFastsimExporter::WriteToDisk, this, pTmp, uiSize);

}
void WriteToDisk(char* pData, unsigned int uiSize)
{
    m_Mtx.lock();
    m_ExportFile.write(pData, uiSize);
    delete[] pData;
    m_Mtx.unlock();
}
boost::thread m_Thread;
boost::mutex  m_Mtx
}
```

is it safe to use the m_Thread that way since the FlushToDisk method can be called while the created thread is executing the WriteToDisk method. 
Or should I do something like:

```
  m_Thread.join();
  m_Thread = boost::thread(&CSimSwcFastsimExporter::WriteToDisk, this, pTmp, uiSize);
```

Would this second solution be slower than the first?

From what i saw at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial
"When the boost::thread object that represents a thread of execution is destroyed the thread becomes detached. Once a thread is detached, it will continue executing until the invocation of the function or callable object supplied on construction has completed, or the program is terminated".
So in my case the threads should not be interrupted or?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second solution will pause the main thread to wait until the writer thread completes. You would be able to remove mutex if you go this way. You are guaranteed to have one file writing thread.

The first solution is going to allow main thread to continue, and will create an uncontrolled writing thread - serialized on the mutex. While you might believe this is better (main thread will not wait) I do not like this solution for several reasons.

First, you do not have any control over the number of created threads. If the function is called often, and the operation is slow, you can easily run out of threads! Second, and much more important, you will accumulate a backlog of detached threads waiting on mutex. If your main application decides to exit, all those threads will be silently killed and the updates will be lost.